# Как реализовать тесты на android?

Tags: java, android

Хочу написать приложение, логические задачки.
Они будут разбиты на категории.

Одна категория - запрос на сервак и закачка массива задач в json.

Далее вопрос отбражения. Первая задача, ответ, далее 2 задача и т.д.
Как реализовать перелистывание с одной задачи на другую, с возможностью подсчета правильных и не правильных ответов в конце .

Answer (score 1):

Ну как пример: создаешь одно активити, со списком категорий. в нем по клику на категорию открывается второе активити, в котором делается запрос на список задач. далее когда список задач получен делаешь следующее:

если на вопросы нужно отвечать по порядку, то так: в окне текст задачи, поле ввода и кнопка. при нажатии на кнопку проверяешь ответ, если верный то увеличиваешь счетчик. проверяешь был ли вопрос последним, если да - то выводишь сообщение о количестве правильных ответов и т.д., если вопрос не последний, то заполняешь поля под след. вопрос.

Это только один из возможных вариантов. Можно использовать фрагменты для отображения каждого вопроса и при ответе на вопрос менять один фрагмент на другой.

Можно использовать viewpager, если нужна возможность перелистывать вопросы, с возможность отвечать в произвольном порядке.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560036/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2

Answer (score 1):

Все можно реализовать на одной активности. Делаешь макет на который например размещаешь картинку и текст. Далее в зависимости от номера задачки программно подгружаешь картинку и вопрос к задачке с вариантами ответа. Пользователь нажал ответ, запоминаешь и меняешь ему картинку текст и варианты ответа.

PS
точнее две активности, на первой список категорий на второй сами задачки